# python 3 subprocess error in bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin, encode

Very good, I have a little problem with the output of the thread, I get in unicode or I think and not let me convert it to utf-8, this is the code:

```
import subprocess,sys,time

string = b'dir'
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', shell=True,cwd="C:\\",stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=None)
process.stdin.write(string)
o,e=process.communicate()
process.wait()
process.stdin.close()
print (o.encode('utf-8'))
```

I jump the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\francisco\Escritorio\k.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (o.encode(utf-8))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**
```

if I print leaving the print and if you let me:

```
print(o)
```

but it prints the following:

```
**b'Microsoft Windows XP [Versi\xa2n 5.1.2600]\r\n(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.\r\n\r\nC:\\>\xa8M\xa0s? '**
```

and if I change these two lines:

```
string = bytes('dir',encoding="utf-8") 
print (n[0].decode("latin"))
```

I print only part of the output

that fails?

---

I've solved this way:

```
process.stdin.write("dir\n".encode())
o,e=process.communicate()
print (o.decode("utf-8"))
```

but I get error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\francisco\Escritorio\k.py", line 6, in 
    print (o.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 103: invalid start byte**

I just print it like this:

```
print (o.decode("latin"))
```

in latin, I can correct this error and print it in utf-8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subprocess "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989808/subprocess-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Answer (score 12):

`o`, the first return value from `proc.communicate()`, is already `bytes` not `str`, so it is already encoded in some encoding (or you could think of it as just a sequence of bytes).

In Python3 `bytes` can be **decoded** to `str`, and `str` can be **encoded** to `bytes`, but `bytes` can never be encoded, and `str` can never be decoded. That is why Python3 is complaining,

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: "In Python3 bytes can be decoded to str". Ok. *How*? Your answer explains why but doesn't give a solution or an example...

Comment: The solution was to add *nothing*. To give a solution to the question, it's like `print (o)` instead of `print (o.decode("latin"))`.