# subprocess "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I'm using this code from [a previously asked question a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844467/7879716), however, I believe this is outdated. Trying to run the code, I receive the error above. I'm still a novice in Python, so I could not get much clarification from similar questions. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
import subprocess

def getLength(filename):
  result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", filename],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
  return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]

print(getLength('bell.mp4'))
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\test3.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(getLength('bell.mp4'))
  File "B:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\test3.py", line 6, in getLength
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
  File "B:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\test3.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`subprocess` returns `bytes` objects for stdout or stderr streams by default. That means you also need to use `bytes` objects in operations against these objects. `"Duration" in x` uses `str` object. Use a bytes literal (note the `b` prefix):

```
return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if b"Duration" in x]
```

or decode your data first, if you know the encoding used (usually, the locale default, but you could [set `LC_ALL` or more specific locale environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html#Locale-Environment-Variables) for the subprocess):

```
return [x for x in result.stdout.read().decode(encoding).splitlines(True)
        if "Duration" in x]
```

The alternative is to tell `subprocess.Popen()` to decode the data to Unicode strings by setting the `encoding` argument to a suitable codec:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffprobe", filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,
    encoding='utf8'
)
```

If you set `text=True` (Python 3.7 and up, in previous versions this version is called `universal_newlines`) you also enable decoding, using your [system default codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding), the same one that is used for `open()` calls. In this mode, the pipes are line buffered by default.

Comment: Maybe point out the `universal_newlines=True` aka `text=True` in Python 3.7+ which causes Python to decode the output as text in the system's default encoding and return a string.

Comment: @tripleee: added.

Comment: The encoding argument of Popen is available from Python 3.6, in previous version (Python 3.5 in my case), you must precise the encoding when doing byte conversion (`bytes("Duration", encoding='utf8')`)

Answer (score 5):

Like the errror says, "Duration" is a string. Whereas, the X is a byte like object as `results.stdout.readlines()` reads the lines in the output as bytecode and not string.

Hence store "Duration" in a variable, say str_var and encode it into a byte array object using `str_var.encode('utf-8')`.

Refer to [this][1].

[1] : [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: It's just a literal, just prefix it with `b`. You don't need to store the string in a variable to be able to encode it either, `"Duration".encode('utf-8')` works too (but is a waste of computer cycles if you can just make it a bytes object to begin with).

Comment: Well, if he wants to use it for multiple files, it's better to store it in a variable. Now, mind explaining why a downvote for that?

Comment: Why? A string literal is stored as a constant with the code object anyway, and where are they mentioning multiple files?

Comment: Note that the test is done in a loop, using a literal is *better there* because that loads a constant, rather than having to look up a variable each time.

Comment: Fair enough but still doesn't explain the downvote. It's not a wrong answer.