# subprocess python reading output

Tags: python

I am trying to run a command using subprocess in python and trying to read the output of it and copy it into a file.
my code is:

```
    command = "%s -sK:\\run_one_test.csh %s %s" % (PATH, file, VERSION)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    text = p.communicate()[0]
    return_code = p.returncode




    with open("%s/%s%s" % (LOG_DIR, file, LOG_EXT), "w") as f:


        f.writelines([l.decode for l in text.split('\n')])

        f.close()
```

But when i use splitlines i get the error message:

```
    f.writelines([l.decode for l in text.split('\n')])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Why does it happen? I used decode. 
Also, is this the right way to split the lines of code using "\n"?
Thanks.

Comment: Follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989808/subprocess-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-python-2

Answer (score 1):

`text` is the result of `subprocess.Popen`, in python 3, this is a `bytes` object. You cannot split it using a string (`text.split(b"\n")` would work, but there are more problems in your code so forget it).

Then, you're not calling *decode* (missing parentheses). Calling `decode` on `text` would work: `text.decode()`

Now with `split('\n')`, you'll remove the end of lines, so that won't work properly (single-line file, ouch). You'd need:

```
f.writelines(text.decode().splitlines(True))
```

(the `True` argument tells the function to keep the end of line chars)

But after all why splitting to write the lines again?, just write the file as it was dumped, as `bytes`, without post-processing:

```
with open("%s/%s%s" % (LOG_DIR, file, LOG_EXT), "wb") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

but why storing the output to write it back to a file then? just pass the file handle to `subprocess.call`:

```
with open("%s/%s%s" % (LOG_DIR, file, LOG_EXT), "wb") as f:
   retcode = subprocess.call(command,stdout=f)
```

or to force an exception if command returncode is not 0:

```
   subprocess.check_call(command,stdout=f)
```

So depending if you want to post-process the lines, post-process the buffer, or not post-process at all, you can choose one of the 3 (possibly modified) solutions above.

Side note: don't compose the command as string, just pass the arguments so:

```
command = "%s -sK:\\run_one_test.csh %s %s" % (PATH, file, VERSION)
```

becomes:

```
command = [PATH,"-sK:\\run_one_test.csh",file,VERSION]
```

(as a bonus, the quoting is handled automatically if needed)

Comment: You should probably prefer `subprocess.check_call()` or better yet `subprocess.run()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Comment: `run` requires python 3.5. I swtiched to `call` because it's a better match for `Popen`. We don't know what the return code of the command will be